# Weird behavior of SpringBootTest based Spock specifications

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-aop, spock, spring-test

Given I have web application which also has Spring Integration pipeline which contains `EvaluationHandler`, I'd like to simulate business processing failure. I created following aspect:

```
@Aspect
class FailureSimulator {
    @Before("execution(* *..*EvaluationHandler+.handle(..))")
    static void fail() {
        simulateBusinessProcessingFailure();
    }

    private static void simulateBusinessProcessingFailure() {
        throw new DataIntegrityViolationException("Simulated failure.");
    }
}
```

whereas `EvaluationHandler` is `org.springframework.integration.dsl.support.GenericHandler`

I created Spock specification which imports `FailureSimulator`

```
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
@Import(FailureSimulator)
class JmsSimulatedBusinessFailureSpec extends Specification {
    private static final String ACTIVEMQ_DLQ = "ActiveMQ.DLQ"
    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate

    def "business processing failure"() {
        when: "I send a message to JMS upstream queue"

        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(UPSTREAM_EVENT_QUEUE, message)

        then: "message is retried 6 times and parked in DLQ"
        jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(25000L)
        def msg = jmsTemplate.receive(ACTIVEMQ_DLQ) as ActiveMQTextMessage
        msg != null
    }
}
```

when I run this `Specification` alone, it works

But, when I run it after another `Specification` which is based on `AbstractResourceProcessorSpec`:

```
@SpringBootTest
abstract class AbstractResourceProcessorSpec extends Specification {}
```

the test fails, because `FailureSimulator` doesn't kick in.

It is not executed even though I can see `org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory - Found AspectJ method: public static void foo.FailureSimulator.fail()` in logs

I was also looking at `org.springframework.test.context.cache - Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics` logs and I found there are 2 contexts cached what is expected because of different annotations on both `Specification`s

When I add `@DirtiesContext` to `Specification` based on `AbstractResourceProcessorSpec` and reexecute tests in a row, it works.

There's gotta be something going on with `ApplicationContext`s being cached in `ContextCache` in `DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate`. Or it is something else, but I don't know what it could be.

Does anybody have any clue?

**ADDED:**
I compared beans in both `Specification`s and `JmsSimulatedBusinessFailureSpec` has 2 additional beans: `org.springframework.boot.test.context.ImportsContextCustomizer$ImportsCleanupPostProcessor` and `FailureSimulator`

**ADDED sample:**
https://github.com/pmihalcin/weird-spring-boot-test-behavior

Comment: I tried your code sample, the test is passed even without `@Import(FailureSimulator)` and any cases extending or not from `AbstractResourceProcessorSpec`. Try to clean or re-import your project in IDE

Comment: Are you sure? For me it is like I described in README. Have you tried executing both tests in a row?. I added screenshot how to set up run configuration in Intellij.

Comment: To be a independent on running tests via IDE, add plugin for generating test report by maven. Because for my tests still passed, but maven test goal skips test execution (i trying throwing exception in test and maven did not react, but IDE showing that test failed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from Andy Wilkinson from Gitter channel:

Your two tests are using different configuration so you have two application contexts running. Spring Framework caches contexts (keeps them running) for the lifetime of the JVM so that they can be reused. As a result, when the second test runs you have two message listener containers (one from each context) listening to the same queue. The listener from the first test is winning. It has the plain unadvised `EvaluationHandler` so the simulated error doesn’t occur. Adding `@DirtiesContext` to the first test stops it from being cached so the test framework closes the context when the test is completed. This then allows the second test’s listener to retrieve the message and it’s then handled by the advised handler and the simulated error occurs.

Recommendation:
You could either use `@DirtiesContext` or perhaps you can customize something in the simulated failure case so that it uses a different queue?
Or perhaps you could start and stop the listener container in `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` while keeping the context cached

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@MockBean` for your `EvaluationHandler` instead of using aspect to simulate system failure.